# How do I check if an ID contains a certain phrase?

Tags: java, android

I am making a simple app with four scores, each score having an add button and a subtract button. To make code simpler, I named each button's `onClick` to `addScore` or `subScore`. Each button's ID contains something such as `android:@+id/team1AddButton`. I need to check in the `onClick` which team is being affected for both `onClick`s.

The button code is simple (removed most formatting code):

```
<Button
           android:id="@+id/team1AddButton"
           android:layout_width="55dp"
           android:layout_height="75dp"
           android:text="+"
           android:onClick="addScore" />

<Button
           android:id="@+id/team1SubButton"
           android:layout_width="55dp"
           android:layout_height="75dp"
           android:text="-"
           android:onClick="addScore" />
```

The Java code is what I'm having trouble with.

```
public void addScore(View v) {
        if (v.getId().toString().contains("team1"));

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what are you looking for:

```
public void addScore(View v) {
    String resourceName = getResources().getResourceName(v.getId());
    String[] parts = resourceName.split("/");
    String result = parts[parts.length - 1];
    
    if (result.contains("team1")) {
        //..
    }
}
```

resourceName value will be like: `packageName:id/team1AddButton`

So if we split the string by "/" and take the last part, we get the result.

or

```
public void addScore(View v) {
   String resourceName = getResources().getResourceName(v.getId());

   if (resourceName.contains("team1")) {
       //..
   }
}
```

If exact resourceName doesn't required then just check if contains or not.

Hope it helps!

Comment: when I run line 2 and then log `resourceName`, I get the number "2131361815".  I should get team1AddButton, right?

Comment: You should get: **yourPackageName:id/team1AddButton** If we assume that your package name is com.example.app then resource name should be: **com.example.app/id:team1AddButton** I have checked twice and result is like this

Comment: I had the second bit of code used  it's working now!

Answer (score 0):

You can't get view's id with string type.If you call view.getId(),it'll return an Integer value.

try this

```
if(view.getId() == R.id.team1AddButton){
        
}else if(view.getId() == R.id.team1SubButton){
        
}
```